# How to use ElevationEffect from Controls.Material 2.0

Tags: qt, qml, material-design, qtquickcontrols2

I've found out that the new Material style for Quick Controls 2 uses ElevationEffect in the implementation of different controls, but it seems that this effect cannot be used by myself because it's just not included in the module. Is there any legit way to use that effect for my own qml objects e.g. custom card element without just copy-pasting it from the source folder?

Comment: Would it be sufficient to use `Pane { Material.elevation: 8 }` to build an elevated card? If I remember correctly, the corners of an elevated Pane were made rounded after the 5.7.0 release, though.

Comment: Well, it would be ok to use panes just for that ,but it has elevation coded in the background item which will be overriden if I'll try to change it. Still, I'll try to make it work for me in some way, maybe draw the pane underneath the actual `Rectangle` with proper color and radius properties set

Comment: `Material.background` should help with getting any desired background color. If this is not sufficient, either import the internal .impl at your own risk, or make a copy.

Comment: Guess those two are the only viable workaround for now, thanks for the reply

Comment: Out of curiosity, what else do you need besides setting an arbitrary background color, and the corner radius that has been fixed in Qt 5.7.1?

Comment: I wanted to make a floating action button and a simple card element, so besides setting a color and radius there was nothing else I needed. Also, corner radius is fixed in just Controls 2.0 module but in material style you'll still have to override background because it has just color and layer effect properties.